# How do I verify/check/test/validate my SSH passphrase?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I think I forgot the passphrase for my SSH key, but I have a hunch what it might be.  How do I check if I'm right?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can verify your SSH key passphrase by attempting to load it into your SSH agent. With [OpenSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH) this is done via `ssh-add`.

Once you're done, remember to unload your SSH passphrase from the terminal by running `ssh-add -d`.

Comment: ssh-add requires admin rights on the machine, I think.  I am getting an error: "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: No, it requires a running authentication agent. Modify your startup scripts or options to bring one up.

Comment: [Rob's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23666831/641451) is the correct answer.

Comment: *If* you happen to be using selinux, you might also want to check the context of the home directory and .ssh files! I was lucky enough to be able to use this simple fix: `# restorecon -R -v /home/user` To check if this is the problem (though the preceding command shouldn't cause any issues), you can use `$ ls -lZR <home_dir>` to examine the context. If you don't see `user_home_t` on the home directory and `ssh_home_t` on the `.ssh` directory and `authorized_keys` file, then use `restorecon` to fix them.

Comment: Robs answer is the correct answer; this command only results in the error message "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." So unless you have the exact setup that this poster then it is no answer; its just a version of "works on my machine'

Answer (score 791):

> ssh-keygen -y

`ssh-keygen -y` will prompt you for the passphrase (if there is one).

If you input the **correct** passphrase, it will show you the associated public key.
    If you input the **wrong** passphrase, it will display `load failed`.
    If the key has **no** passphrase, it will **not** prompt you for a passphrase and will immediately show you the associated public key.

*Note that the order of arguments is important. `-y` **must** come before `-f input_keyfile`, else you will get the error `Too many arguments.`*

---

e.g.,

Create a new public/private key pair, with or without a passphrase:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f /tmp/my_key
...
```

Now see if you can access the key pair:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f /tmp/my_key
```

Following are extended examples, with example output.

---

**Behavior with a passphrase:**

First, create a new public/private key pair, with a passphrase:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f /tmp/my_key_with_passphrase
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /tmp/my_key_with_passphrase.
Your public key has been saved in /tmp/my_key_with_passphrase.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
de:24:1b:64:06:43:ca:76:ba:81:e5:f2:59:3b:81:fe rob@Robs-MacBook-Pro.local
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|     .+          |
|   . . o         |
|    = . +        |
|   = + +         |
|  o = o S .      |
|   + = + *       |
|    = o o .      |
|     . .         |
|      E          |
+-----------------+
```

Now attempt to access the key pair by inputting the **correct passphrase**.
Note that the public key will be shown and the exit status (`$?`) will be `0` to indicate success:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f /tmp/my_key_with_passphrase
Enter passphrase:
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDBJhVYDYxXOvcQw0iJTPY64anbwSyzI58hht6xCGJ2gzGUJDIsr1NDQsclka6s0J9TNhUEBBzKvh9nTAYibXwwhIqBwJ6UwWIfA3HY13WS161CUpuKv2A/PrfK0wLFBDBlwP6WjwJNfi4NwxA21GUS/Vcm/SuMwaFid9bM2Ap4wZIahx2fxyJhmHugGUFF9qYI4yRJchaVj7TxEmquCXgVf4RVWnOSs9/MTH8YvH+wHP4WmUzsDI+uaF1SpCyQ1DpazzPWAQPgZv9R8ihOrItLXC1W6TPJkt1CLr/YFpz6vapdola8cRw6g/jTYms00Yxf2hn0/o8ORpQ9qBpcAjJN
$ echo $?
0
```

Now attempt to access the key pair by inputting an **incorrect passphrase**.
Note that the `load failed` error message will be displayed (message may differ depending on OS) and the exit status (`$?`) will be `1` to indicate an error:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f /tmp/my_key_with_passphrase
Enter passphrase:
load failed
$ echo $?
1
```

---

**Behavior with no passphrase:**
First, create a new public/private key pair, **without** a passphrase:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f /tmp/my_key_with_no_passphrase
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /tmp/my_key_with_no_passphrase
Your public key has been saved in /tmp/my_key_with_no_passphrase.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:wx2N90FB68dUM9DnFXkUm/2RoiWV0hjF3N29D5TBeDo robbednark@Robs-MacBook-Pro.local
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|           .BBXXX|
|           =o*==/|
|          o.+*o*B|
|       . . oEoo=+|
|        S .. .o.=|
|         .     ..|
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

Now attempt to access that key pair.  Note that there is no prompt for the passphrase, the public key will be displayed, and the exit status (`$?`) will be `0` to indicate success:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f /tmp/my_key_with_no_passphrase
ssh-rsa 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 robbednark@Robs-MacBook-Pro.local
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: If there is no password, it will just print out the associated public key.

Comment: Thanks @Kyrremann!  I have now updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: `ssh-keygen -y` asks for the key file and offers a default when click return as one would expect.

Comment: I've used `ssh-keygen -y` to check the passphrase of my ssh key. It worked fine except my Ubuntu become incredible slow. Most of the programs could start up in a minute or more while the CPU usage was 100%. After restarting my laptop I could log in hardly as it took minutes to see my desktop. Finally I've found [this issue on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788075/ubuntu-16-04-some-applications-take-too-long-to-start-up). I had to start by `gnome-keyring-daemon` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Note that the order of arguments is important `ssh-keygen -f -y /to/my-key` does not work: `Too many arguments.`

Comment: WORKED, I used my system password!

Answer (score 22):

The best answer so far, that I found on the web is:

```
ssh-keygen -y -P "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

That will attempt to read the private key with the passphrase as **empty string**. That will show a public key perfectly fine if you have a key with **no** passphrase.

Otherwise the app will exit with an error code and the message:

```
Load key "~/.ssh/id_rsa": incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
```

Comment: At least a solution that we can use in a shell script!

Answer (score 7):

Extending @RobBednark's solution to a specific Windows + PuTTY scenario, you can do so:

1. Generate SSH key pair with PuTTYgen (following *[Manually generating your SSH key in Windows](https://docs.joyent.com/public-cloud/getting-started/ssh-keys/generating-an-ssh-key-manually/manually-generating-your-ssh-key-in-windows)*), saving it to a PPK file;
2. With the context menu in Windows Explorer, choose Edit with PuTTYgen. It will prompt for a password.

If you type the wrong password, it will just prompt again.

Note, if you like to type, use the following command on a folder that contains the PPK file: `puttygen private-key.ppk -y`.

Answer (score 1):

Use "ssh-keygen -p". You can add "-f "

It will prompt you for the old password. If the password is correct, it will prompt to enter a new password. If the old password is incorrect, you will get "Failed to load key <...>".

Answer (score 0):

If your passphrase is to unlock your SSH key and you don't have `ssh-agent`, but do have sshd (the SSH daemon) installed on your machine, do:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys;
ssh localhost -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Where `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is the public key, and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is the private key.

Comment: It Does not ask for a pass phrase doing this

Comment: It does for me, to unlock the private id_rsa to ssh localhost

Comment: I get an error: "ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Bad file number"

Comment: "ssh: connect to host localhost post 22: Bad file number" is sshd running on your local machine? Is it possible that you have a software-firewall preventing access?