# SSH GIT Clone with Private and Public Keys

Tags: git, ssh

I was given the following details to clone a git repository from a server.

- Address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- Port: xx
- User: user

  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED

DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,F1447CCDBBC8B2BCF6D12D0AAE5B96D7

TVuVfjbsoO+eimi6TmFJqwyjIWzUapZH8R17ddXAdl9Gpflvwmfhd7l8v1NkOFu2

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

ssh-rsa

AAAAB3NzgvhjkljhgvEq9nFJR+Dqs/Uq0F0qJQYpwEBTe7rkerGFS1hJalu6d

8KpklV9G4P
GXNY2mBNWwwnWvtiHXw0VGfJO6x6LFhf0Ss7ZM5RDyH9CNR5vrxzM7LWjCAcHi6X5HhgEABpsi1SG

uubyZYIJYggEP84sqEtVzMTLWJkw==

cxxx@gvhhh.com

and a passphrase.

My Action are as follows on a Mac Yosemite;
  Added the private key to a file named file_rsa
 Added the Public key to a file name file_rsa.pub.

I did a ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/file_rsa

but it asked for passphrase which I added, but kept getting 
"Bad Passphrase"
Then I did a git clone user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/file.git

I keep getting permission error.

What could possible be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your passphrase is correct.
you can do this by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411457/how-do-i-verify-check-test-validate-my-ssh-password).

Here is an extract of what you can do to check if your passphrase is correct:

> ssh-keygen -y will challenge you for the passphrase (if there is one).

```
If you input the correct passphrase, it will show you the associated public key.
If you input the wrong passphrase, it will display load failed.
```