# How do I find my SSH-Key Passphrase on MacOS?

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I recently tried to cloned one of my own repos on Github.

I haven't cloned a repo in a while, and as such; I forgot my **"SSH-Key Passphrase"** and couldn't clone it.

I am running **"macOs Monterey"**.

I looked everywhere and couldn't find it on my Mac.

- I looked in the **~/.ssh/id_rsa** file for it,
- and even checked the **~/.ssh/identity** file and could not find where it was.

I searched **StackOverflow** and the **StackExchange** and all I saw was [How do I verify/check/test/validate my SSH passphrase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411457/how-do-i-verify-check-test-validate-my-ssh-passphrase) and [SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase) but they are both outdated and only say to delete it and start fresh.

Even [Github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases) says to change it but to do that, you have to know the old passphrase. It says nothing about "**How do I find my SSH-Key Passphrase on MacOS?**"

Answer (score 8):

I looked everywhere on **"How do I find my SSH-Key Passphrase on MacOS?"**.

If you have saved the **password** to the **Keychain**, then you can find a solution [here](https://findanyanswer.com/how-do-i-find-my-ssh-key-passphrase).

If you're tired of searching, I also placed **the steps for it below**.

> **Recovering your SSH key passphrase**
>
> 1. In Finder, search for the **Keychain Access** app.
> 2. In **Keychain Access**, search for **SSH**.
> 3. **Double click** on the entry for your **SSH Key** to open a new dialog box.
> 4. In the **lower-left corner**, select Show Password.
> 5. You'll be prompted for your **administrative password**.
> 6. Your **password** will be **revealed**.

Answer (score 1):

If you've saved the passphrase someplace, then you should be able to recover it from that place. (I hope it's a secure place, and not a note attached to your monitor.)

However: **If you haven't saved the passphrase someplace, then you cannot recover the passphrase from the key.**

(A passphrase that you can extract from the key it protects is about as secure as taping a door key to the door it opens, with a big sign that says "USE THIS KEY TO UNLOCK THIS DOOR" and also maybe some brightly-dressed people singing "USE THAT KEY" to a catchy tune while dancing and pointing to the key.)